# Median of Rayleigh Distribution

Tags: density-function, median, rayleigh-distribution

I am not sure how to solve the following problem:

The probability density function of the Rayleigh distribution is,

$\ f(x;α) = \frac{x}{α^2} e^\frac{-x^2}{2α^2},  x ≥ 0, $

where α is the scale parameter of the distribution. Find the median of the Rayleigh distribution.

I need to derive the median of the distribution, but do not know how to do so. Thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Rayleigh distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution) has [cumulative distribution function (CDF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) $F_X(x) = 1-\text{e}^{\frac{-x^2}{2\alpha^2}}$.

Denote the median $q_{50}$.

Starting with the CDF...

$$\begin{align}
1-\text{e}^{\frac{-q_{50}^2}{2\alpha^2}} &= 0.5 \\
\text{e}^{\frac{-q_{50}^2}{2\alpha^2}} &= 0.5 \\
\frac{-q_{50}^2}{2\alpha^2} &= \text{ln}(0.5) \\
-q_{50}^2 &= 2\alpha^2 \text{ln}(0.5) \\
 \\
q_{50} &=\alpha \sqrt{-2 \text{ln}(0.5)} \\
&= \alpha \sqrt{2\text{ln}(2)} \quad \quad \square
\end{align}$$

See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/374363/177387) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution) for general quantiles.

---

Update: Based on comments amounting to "can I do this from the PDF," yes, it is possible but requires a little more effort (integration).

You can solve $\int_0^{q_{50}} f_X(x)dx = 0.5$ for $q_{50}$.

$$\begin{align}\int_0^{q_{50}} f_X(x)dx &= 0.5 \\
\int_0^{q_{50}} \frac{x}{\alpha^2}\text{e}^{-x^2/(2\alpha^2)} dx&= 0.5 \\
1-\text{e}^{\frac{-q_{50}^2}{2\alpha^2}} &= 0.5 \\
&\text{Continue using CDF approach above}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Right, because this is a CRV I should use the CDF. Thanks!!

Comment: Discrete random variables also have a CDF.  I would rather you say since the median (50th-quantile) is an inverse of the CDF, it makes sense to start with the CDF and simply invert.  That's how I think about this problem at least.

Comment: My point was that since this is a CRV, it would be incorrect to use the PMF. However, I understand your point. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @JoeAdemo, I've added the approach starting from the PDF.